# Debian stuck on login screen loop after homebrew install

Tags: debian, boot, login, reboot, homebrew

I installed homebrew today on Debian buster. After a reboot, it's not going past the initial login screen even with correct password. But I am able to log onto console.
I think I messed up the ./profile file.

while installing brew first I ran this command from their homepage

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

then these commands

```
test -d ~/.linuxbrew && eval $(~/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv) 
test -d /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew && eval $(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv) 
 test -r ~/.bash_profile && echo "eval \$($(brew --prefix)/bin/brew shellenv)" 
 >>~/.bash_profile echo "eval \$($(brew --prefix)/bin/brew shellenv)" >>~/.profile
```

in the third command, I changed the ~/.bash_profile to ~/.profile (that caused the issue i think)

In the console after logging in its showing this
[image: console output]

what can I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ORIGINAL SOLUTION](https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/k75bq5/debian_stuck_on_login_screen_after_homebrew/geoxnhw?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

- shutdown pc and boot from a live usb
- delete your ~/.profile file and copy paste the .profile from /etc/skel/.profile
- reboot
- you can do this from console too but I wasn't able to so I used live usb method.